# Typing in Dropdown angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular select for dropdown but there are lot of items inside it so I wanna give typing and search facility to user so that as he type in dropdown it will auto popup matching records. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Vivek

Comment: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using angular-ui's select2

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2

Comment: It has been deprecated by the angular-ui team.